LaTeX with UltiSnips: How to automatically insert backslash in front of every math variable?
I use LaTeX inside Vim with Vim-tex and Ultisnips. The majority of my snippets are those created by Gilles Castel. In one of his snippets, he writes the following:
priority 200
context "math()"
snippet '(?<!\\)(arcsin|arccos|arctan|arccot|arccsc|arcsec|pi|zeta|int)' "ln" rwA
\\`!p snip.rv = match.group(1)`
endsnippet

What this does is it puts a backslash automatically in front of the arguments specified, i.e. arcsin becomes \arcsin. I really like this functionality so I decided to add many more arguments, such as rho, mu, gamma, Gamma, vec, Phi, omega, ...
Now whenever I open tex.snippets (the file containing this code) I get the following warning message:
E363: Pattern uses more memory than 'maxmempattern'

This does not cause the file to break or anything and I've looked this error up and seen how to resolve this message, but I wonder whether there is a more efficient way to capture what the above code does. I realize to some this may seem a ridiculous waste of time and effort to try and achieve such functionality, but at least for me, not having to press backslash so frequently really helps with speed as well as reducing hand-strain.

The thing I still don't get about this question is why E363 would show when you open the snippets file. Again, I know next to nothing about that plugin but shouldn't those snippets only trigger in a LaTeX file? If not, is running the snippet on itself causing this?

Looks like a case where using a plugin creates more problems than it solves.
To be frank, I've never used UltiSnips and have little idea how it works or what problems it solves.
To me, it looks like this could be trivially solved using abbreviations.
See :help abbreviations for reference.
Adding the following lines to your .vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim should do what you want:
iabbrev <buffer> Gamma \Gamma
iabbrev <buffer> Phi \Phi
iabbrev <buffer> arccos \arccos
iabbrev <buffer> arccot \arccot
iabbrev <buffer> arccsc \arccsc
iabbrev <buffer> arcsec \arcsec
iabbrev <buffer> arcsin \arcsin
iabbrev <buffer> arctan \arctan
iabbrev <buffer> cos \cos
iabbrev <buffer> gamma \gamma
iabbrev <buffer> int \int
iabbrev <buffer> mu \mu
iabbrev <buffer> omega \omega
iabbrev <buffer> pi \pi
iabbrev <buffer> rho \rho
iabbrev <buffer> vec \vec
iabbrev <buffer> zeta \zeta

Doesn't this look neat?
One line per abbreviation, one abbreviation per line, sorted alphabetically (or any way you like).
No magic, no surprises, no domain specific language.
As a caveat, these won't be context-sensitive, i.e. they will expand anywhere in your LaTeX document, not just in math mode.
To prevent expansion, type Ctrl-V at the end of the abbreviation, e.g. cos<C-V><Space>.
Collisions should happen only very rarely, however, as you would talk about cosine in text.
You asked about efficiency. I didn't perform any measurements but my gut feeling tells me that using one of Vim's built-in features that does little more than string comparison is bound to be vastly more efficient than running a plugin that interprets its own meta-language to create a regular expression.

In fact it's "metalanguage" is mostly Python, IIRC.

Now that you mention it, match.groups() looks familiar. My point is you would also have to know how to put it all together using the decidedly non-Python priority and context keywords. Maybe I should have written "creole" instead.

Just to cover something not mentioned by other answers: as you know, E363 is the following according to :help:
                            *E363*
    When Vim runs into the limit it gives an error message and mostly
    behaves like CTRL-C was typed.
    Running into the limit often means that the pattern is very
    inefficient or too complex.  This may already happen with the pattern
    "\(.\)*" on a very long line.  ".*" works much better.

So the problem is clearly that the pattern is too long or too complex. This suggests a simple solution: move your other patterns into a new snippet with a simpler pattern. Abbreviations would (in this case) be even simpler, however.

I would try:
priority 200
context "math()"
snippet '(?<!\\)((arc(sin|cos|tan|cot|csc|sec))|pi|zeta|int)' "ln" rwA
\\`!p snip.rv = match.group(1)`
endsnippet

I belive the regular expression engine has less backtracking options to consider. I cannot test it at the moment but I believe it is worth testing.

And why would you try that?

I belive the regular expression engine has less backtracking options to consider. I cannot test it at the moment but I believe it is worth testing. Do you think it is silly?

Another "I would try code" post rescued from the low quality posts queue. I took the liberty of editing your explanation into the answer to give a little background. Feel free to improve.
